# Python mysql.connector module, Passing data into string VALUES %s

Tags: python, mysql

I'm having trouble passing data into %s token. I've looked around and noticed that this Mysql module handles the %s token differently, and that it should be escaped for security reasons, my code is throwing this error.

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your
 SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for
the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1

If I do it like this:

```
sql_insert = ("INSERT INTO `Products` (title) VALUES(%s)"),(data)
```

I get a tuple error..

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

cnx = mysql.connector.connect (user='userDB1', password='UserPwd1',
host='somedatabase.com', database='mydatabase1')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

sql_insert = ("INSERT INTO `Products` (title) VALUES(%s)")

data=('HelloSQLWORLD')

cursor.execute(sql_insert,data)

cnx.commit()


cnx.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, don't do it the way @Jeon suggested - by using string formatting you are exposing your code to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead, *properly parameterize the query*:

```
query = """
    INSERT INTO 
        Products 
        (title) 
    VALUES
        (%s)"""

cursor.execute(query, ('HelloSQLWORLD', ))
```

Note how the query parameters are put into a *tuple*.

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I was looking for although @Jeon's solution would work, this method is best due to vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic string formatting is:

```
str1 = 'hello'
str2 = 'world'
'%s, %s' % (str1, str2)
```

Use `%` with `tuple`, not `,`

For your particular case, try:

```
cursor.execute(sql_insert % (data))
```

Comment: Sorry, have to downvote, `,` here is perfectly valid - it is a delimiter between arguments to `execute()`. The second argument to `execute()` are the query parameters. This is not about Pythonic vs not, this is about a proper way to insert parameters into the query and a wrong way to do it. Thanks for understanding.